# Unmap project without physical deletion in VS2013 + Visual Studio Team Services (was TFS Online)

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs, azure-devops

I have Team project in TFS, and I map it to folder "Common projects" with many projects inside, by example

- Common projects

  - prj1
  - prj2
  - ..
  - prjn

TFS adds all of them and it slows my machine. I want to unmap most of them, but if I make "Remove mapping" for prj1, it also deletes its folder physically from my hard drive. Is there a way to map projects in mapped folder selectively, and leave other on harddrive? Or I need to create separate folder especially for synchronization with TFS..

**upd.:**
I update my post with answer as I understand from google that people searching the solution.

Step 1: File-> Source control-> Advanced-> Workspaces-> Remove, click "**No**" when popup dialog appears. But after this on next random "Get"(on other project in other folder) - files will be deleted from local, becouse TFS "remembers" associations even they are removed from Workspace. To prevent it - step 2:

[image: Team menu->disconnect]

p.s.: try it on Your own risk, make backups and tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for something called Cloaking. By using cloaking, you can map a root folder to a local workspace. As you've noticed, this implicitly downloads all the sub folders beneath the root folder.

When you now select a sub folder you don't want, you can select Cloak. This means that the sub folder (and anything beneath it) won't be downloaded to your pc.

The MSDN topic [Optimize your workspace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181378(v=vs.140).aspx#mappings) has the info you need. If you look at the example, you want to perform step 2 and 4.

Comment: Hi Wouter de Kort! Thank You for response! As I understand Your answer - TFS folder structure is closely related to actual folder structure, so I can not map subfolders selectively in full sense, but I can exclude some of them marking them as cloaked.

Comment: If you want to map subfolders selectively, you would get multiple workspaces. If you map the root folder to one workspace and then hide certain subfolders wit cloaking you have less maintenance and an easier structure.